# What are the circumstances where autovacuum can be disabled?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table where I am performing only inserts, never deletes/updates. I notice sometimes that autovacuum runs on this table, even though this is the case.

```
autovacuum: VACUUM ANALYZE public.twitter_shares (to prevent wraparound)
```

It is taking a long time, and it is having an impact on the performance of my DB. Is it safe for me to just disable autovacuum for this table? Since I am not performing deletes/updates, I don't understand why autovacuum is even needed, and why postgres decides to run it.

Answer (score 2):

> (to prevent wraparound)

is the key bit. PostgreSQL must do freeze vacuums where transaction IDs are set to XID_FROZEN to prevent transaction ID wrap-around, and as a result massive data corruption.

If you disable these or cancel them all the time your database will eventually go into emergency shutdown.

See [the user manual on `VACUUM`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-WRAPAROUND).

You can do a manual `VACUUM FREEZE` during a quiet period to get this all over and done with in one go if you want.

Comment: When are new transaction IDS created? When I do an insert or update?

Comment: @HenleyChiu Any read/write statement will create a new xid if the transaction doesn't already have one. So will some other operations - I think `WITH HOLD` cursors do; selecting `txid_current()` certainly does, etc.

Comment: Can I disable auovacuum transaction wrap-around for this table if I'm no longer doing future inserts/updates (ie it's an archive table)

Comment: @HenleyChiu You can do a manual `VACUUM FREEZE`, which is what autovacuum is trying to do anyway. Once all tuples are frozen there's no need for autovacuum to do any more work on the table.

Comment: I expect checkpoint also (consumes) xids.

Comment: @Jasen I don't think checkpoints assign XIDs actually. I don't see why they'd need to, anyway.

Comment: oh yeah I meant `savepoint` sorry.